# How to insert a table with J2ME?

Tags: java-me

I'm developing a mobile application with netbeans 7.2.1 and I use LWUIT Framework. I want to know where can I write a code to insert a table, that the user can fill, in which file?

Answer (score 1):

This blog and link might help. Set the cell value to be editable so that you can ass the data.
http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2010/06/headon-that-table.html